# Background color of section is not apply when use bootstrap grid

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

when i am apply background color to`<section>`without bootstrap grid it is working but when create`<div class="row">`and into that`<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6">`background color is hide. and when specifying height to`<section>`then its working but I want height auto.

Comment: create a fiddle with your issue

Comment: How to create that please tell me. I am beginner in to Bootstrap.

Comment: just put your code here - http://jsfiddle.net/pjBzY/62/  save it and give us a link

Comment: I got it brother. I just have to add all <section> to overflow: auto;